# How do I call a function using a specific time window?

Tags: r, dataframe, zoo, rollapply

Suppose I have a zoo object (or it could be a data.frame) that has an index on "time of day" and has some value (see sample data below):

```
                    val
...
2006-08-01 12:00    23
2006-08-01 12:01    24
2006-08-01 12:02    25
2006-08-01 12:03    26
2006-08-01 12:04    27
2006-08-01 12:05    28
2006-08-01 12:06    29
...
2006-08-02 12:00    123
2006-08-02 12:01    124
2006-08-02 12:02    125
2006-08-02 12:03    126
2006-08-02 12:04    127
...
```

I would like to call a custom function (call it `custom.func(vals)`) from 12:01 - 12:03 (i.e. something similar to zoo::rollapply) every time that interval occurs so in this example, daily. How would I do that?

---

NOTES (for robustness, it would also be great to take into account the following edge cases but not necessary):

1. Don't assume that I have values for 12:01 - 12:03 every day
2. Don't assume that the entire range 12:01 - 12:03 is present every day. Some days I might only have 12:01 and 12:02 but might be missing 12:03
3. What if I wanted my `custom.func(vals)` to be called on day boundaries like using `val` from 23:58 - 00:12?

Comment: Do you want to create rolling function on 3-minutes window span?

Comment: window spanning a particular time range every day (in the sample case)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose our input is the POSIXct zoo object `z` given in the Note at the end.

Create a character vector `times` which has one element per element of `z` and is in the form HH:MM.  Then create a logical `ok` which indicates which times are between the indicated boundary values.  `z[ok]` is then `z` reduced to those values.  Finally for each day apply `sum` (can use some other function if desired) using `aggregate.zoo` :

```
times <- format(time(z), "%H:%M")
ok <- times >= "12:01" & times <= "12:03"
aggregate(z[ok], as.Date, sum)
## 2006-08-01 2006-08-02 
##         75        375
```

### times straddle midnight

The version is for the case where the times straddle midnight. Note that the order of values sent to the function is not the original order but if the function is symmetric that does not matter.

```
times <- format(time(z), "%H:%M")
ok <- times >= "23:58" | times <= "00:12"
aggregate(z[ok], (as.Date(format(time(z))) + (times >= "23:58"))[ok], sum)
## 2006-08-02 
##         41
```

### Variation

The prior code chunk works if the function is symmetric in the components of its argument (which is the case for many functions such as `mean` and `sum`) but if the function were not symmetric we would need a slightly different approach.  We define `to.sec` which translates an HH:MM string to numeric seconds and subtract `to.sec("23:58")` from each POSIXct datetime.  Then the components of `z` to keep are those whose transformed times converted to HH:MM character strings that are less than "00:14".

```
to.sec <- function(x) with(read.table(text = x, sep = ":"), 3600 * V1 + 60 * V2)
times <- format(time(z) - to.sec("23:58"), "%H:%M")
ok <- times <= "00:14"
aggregate(z[ok], as.Date(time(z)[ok] - to.sec("23:58")), sum)
## 2006-08-01 
##         41
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "datetime val
2006-08-01T12:00    23
2006-08-01T12:01    24
2006-08-01T12:02    25
2006-08-01T12:03    26
2006-08-01T12:04    27
2006-08-01T12:05    28
2006-08-01T12:06    29
2006-08-01T23:58    20
2006-08-02T00:01    21
2006-08-02T12:00    123
2006-08-02T12:01    124
2006-08-02T12:02    125
2006-08-02T12:03    126
2006-08-02T12:04    127"

library(zoo)
z <- read.zoo(text = Lines, tz = "", header = TRUE, format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M")
```

### EDIT

Have revised the non-symmetric code and simplified all code chunks.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend [runner](https://cran.r-project.org/package=runner) package which allows to compute any rolling function on irregular time series. Function [runner](https://gogonzo.github.io/runner/reference/runner.html) is equivalent of `rollApply` with distinction that it can depend on dates. `runner` allows to apply any R function on window length defined by `k` with  date `idx` (or any integer). Example below calculates regression on 5-minutes (5*60 sec) window span. Algorithm don't care if there will be day-change, just compute 5-minutes each time (for example 23:56-00:01).

**Create data:**

```
set.seed(1)
x <- cumsum(rnorm(1000))
y <- 3 * x + rnorm(1000)
time <- as.POSIXct(cumsum(sample(60:120, 1000, replace = TRUE)), 
                   origin = Sys.Date()) # unequaly spaced time series
data <- data.frame(time, y, x)
```

**Custom function to be called on sliding windows:**

```
library(runner)

running_regression <- function(idx) {
  predict(lm(y ~ x, data = data))[max(idx)]
}

data$pred <- runner(seq_along(x), 
                    k = 60 * 5,
                    idx = time,
                    f = running_regression)
```

---

Once we have created dataset with rolling 5-minute prediction, then we can filter only particular windows - here, only 1-st minute of the hour. It means that we always keep {hh}:56 - {hh+1}:01

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
filtered <-
  data %>% 
  filter(minute(time) == 1)


plot(data$time, data$y, type = "l", col = "red")
points(filtered$time, filtered$pred, col = "blue")
```

[image]

There are some other examples in [vignette](https://gogonzo.github.io/runner/articles/runner_examples.html) how to do this with `runner`

Comment: but I would like to compute 3-min only between particular times